# Push dynamic values into the data Layer Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am doing some work on a site. A message is passed to the dataLayer updating the variable "u1".

I have searched the container tag and am still unsure of how this is working,
this happens when a user hits the homepage, no push elements on the site.

URL: "premierline.co.uk"

Another example of this is the "u3" variable

URL: https://www.quote.premierline.co.uk/AWE/Container.aspx?CurrentStep=NewClient&CurrentWorkflow=CommercialB2C&ProductTarget=CompleteRetailerUnderwriting

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "u1" and "u3" parameters are being populated via onpage scripting. When you look at the source code on those pages and search for "dataLayer", you'll see this:

```
<script>
   dataLayer = [{
      'u1': 'QWEB MISC'
   }];
</script>
```

and on the other link you'll see this:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
   dataLayer = [{
      'u3': 'XXRX'
   }];
</script>
```